Build error facing while running an android application that uses api
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\akhle\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\akhle.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0458cb6e0a04d92b3261a94970af1327\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\akhle.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0458cb6e0a04d92b3261a94970af1327\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

I want this program to run properly

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Also, it makes more sense if you explain the steps you've taken before encountering that exception. It could cause confusion for us if you refrain from explaining.
